# Empty results in PDO query with JOIN

Tags: php, join, pdo

I'm getting empty results when running this query using PDO. The SQL query checks out in Mysql however.

```
<?php

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT games_images.imgName 
                       FROM games_images 
                       JOIN product 
                       WHERE games_images.imgName LIKE ? 
                         AND product.id=?  ');
$stmt->execute([$Name, $ID]);
$Exists = $stmt->fetchColumn();
print_r($Exists);

?>
```

Comment: Doesn't `JOIN` require an `ON x=y ...`? Also if that is your complete code `$pdo` is not defined

Comment: `print_r($pdo->errorInfo());`

Comment: No @kerbh0lz, but you get a cartesian product.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Ok, thanks, didn't know that